# How to set up Selenium to automate a stand alone desktop webapp (Node-WebKit)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, node-webkit

We have a desktop application written using Node-WebKit, javascript, html and css and packaged into an exe file (here is exactly how it is built http://tutorialzine.com/2015/01/your-first-node-webkit-app/)

All the tutorials I found are for apps that use regular browsers(chrome, IE...). I want to use javascript, Selenium, mocha or any other javascript framework... Any ideas please? Steps or tutorials would be great!

And if that is possible, how to launch an exe file from the tests too.

Just to clarify:
- I want to write the tests in javascript.
- It's already working with C# like this:

```
public ExeApp()
    {
        var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(ExePath _ ExeName);
        service.Start();
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.BinaryLocation = exePath;
        Driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
        Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        //Wait for page to load
    }
```

To login into the app:

```
      Driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
      Driver.FindElement(By.Id(loginWindowId));
      //Wait for page to load
      var loginButton = Driver.FindElement(By.Id(buttonId));
      loginButton.Click();
```

So how to do the same thing in javasript as I'm very new to this language. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be able to if it's not something you can access from a standalone browser.

Comment: It's being done in C# but I'm looking for solutions in javascript. I've updated my original post for more clarifications. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

NW.js provides a customized ChromeDriver compatible with Selenium, so you can test your NW.js app with any clients implementing the Json Wire protocol.
This is an example from the official documentation with Python:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("nwapp=/path/to/your/app")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/nwjs/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)

time.sleep(5) # Wait 5s to see the web page
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5) # Wait 5s to see the search result
driver.quit()
```

For more information:

[NW.js Test with ChromeDriver](http://nwjs.readthedocs.org/en/v0.13.0-beta5/For%20Users/Advanced/Test%20with%20ChromeDriver/)

Comment: It's being done in C# but I'm looking for solutions in javascript. I've updated my original post for more clarifications. Thank you

Comment: You can use any JavaScript client compatible with selenium: selenium-webdriverjs, WD.js, protractor, nightwatch, WebdriverIO ...

Comment: Yes I just wish i knew how!

Comment: The problem is that all of the available resources on the web cover just webrowser apps not apps that are of an exe nature

Comment: It doesn't matter, all the commands are the same once the driver is instantiated. You desktop app is just a borderless browser.